# How can I benchmark performance in Spark console?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have just started using Spark and my interactions with it revolve around `spark-shell` at the moment. I would like to benchmark how long various commands take, but could not find how to get the time or run a benchmark. Ideally I would want to do something super-simple, such as:

```
val t = [current_time]
data.map(etc).distinct().reduceByKey(_ + _)
println([current time] - t)
```

Edit: Figured it out --

```
import org.joda.time._
val t_start = DateTime.now()
[[do stuff]]
val t_end = DateTime.now()
new Period(t_start, t_end).toStandardSeconds()
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you do the following :

```
def time[A](f: => A) = {
  val s = System.nanoTime
  val ret = f
  println("time: " + (System.nanoTime - s) / 1e9 + " seconds")
  ret
}
```

You can pass a function as an argument to time function and it will compute the result of the function giving you the time taken by the function to be performed.

Let's consider a function `foobar` that take data as argument and then do the following :

```
val test = time(foobar(data))
```

`test` will contains the result of `foobar` and you'll get the time needed as well.

Comment: System.nanoTime gives the time in nanoseconds. Your conversion yields millihours :)
 Replace 1e6*60*60 with 1e9 to get the result in seconds.

Comment: I don't ever recall when I wrote this. Thank you !