# Benchmark Spark user defined function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I would like to compare two Spark user defined functions and see which is faster.  Specifically, I'd like to see how much faster `isEvenUdf` runs compared to `isEvenOptionUdf`.

```
def isEven(n: Integer): Boolean = {
  if (n == null) {
    false
  } else {
    n % 2 == 0
  }
}

val isEvenUdf = udf[Boolean, Integer](isEven)

def isEvenOption(n: Integer): Option[Boolean] = {
  val num = Option(n).getOrElse(return Some(false))
  Some(num % 2 == 0)
}

val isEvenOptionUdf = udf[Option[Boolean], Integer](isEvenOption)
```

The [Databricks Scala style guide document](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#perf-option) says "For performance sensitive code, prefer null over Option, in order to avoid virtual method calls and boxing" and that's why I think `isEvenOptionUdf` is slower.  I'd like to quantify how much slower it is.

Spark is difficult to benchmark because everything is evaluated lazily.

Here is what I've looked into:

- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647248/how-can-i-benchmark-performance-in-spark-console) seems a bit oversimplified.
- The [`Benchmark` class that's part of Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Benchmark.scala) is private.
- Databricks has a [`spark-perf` library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-perf), but it doesn't seem easy to use.

Here's how I might be able to benchmark the code.  Create a DataFrame (`df`) that has 1 million numerical values and 1 million `null` values and measure the execution time of this code.

```
df.withColumn("is_even", NumberFun.isEvenUdf(col("number")))
df.cache
df.count // force the DAG to be executed
```

Then I could run the same code with `isEvenOptionUdf` and compare the times.  Let me know if there is a better approach / library.

Comment: Take a look at the SparkMeasure library https://github.com/LucaCanali/sparkMeasure